# numpy.fft.irfft: Why is len(a) necessary?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

The [documentation for `numpy.fft.irfft`, the inverse discrete Fourier transform for real input,](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.irfft.html) states

> This function computes the inverse of the one-dimensional n-point
>   discrete Fourier Transform of real input computed by [`rfft`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html). In other
>   words, `irfft(rfft(a), len(a)) == a` to within numerical accuracy. (See
>   Notes below for why `len(a)` is necessary here.)

However, the Notes section does not seem to indicate why it would be necessary to specify `len(a)` in this case. Indeed, everything seems to work correctly even when omitting the length:

```
numpy.random.seed(123456)
a = numpy.random.rand(20)
# array([0.12696983, 0.96671784, 0.26047601, 0.89723652, 0.37674972,
#        0.33622174, 0.45137647, 0.84025508, 0.12310214, 0.5430262 ,
#        0.37301223, 0.44799682, 0.12944068, 0.85987871, 0.82038836,
#        0.35205354, 0.2288873 , 0.77678375, 0.59478359, 0.13755356])
numpy.fft.irfft(numpy.fft.rfft(a))
# array([0.12696983, 0.96671784, 0.26047601, 0.89723652, 0.37674972,
#        0.33622174, 0.45137647, 0.84025508, 0.12310214, 0.5430262 ,
#        0.37301223, 0.44799682, 0.12944068, 0.85987871, 0.82038836,
#        0.35205354, 0.2288873 , 0.77678375, 0.59478359, 0.13755356])
```

Can I omit `len(a)` in my call to `numpy.fft.rfft`?

Comment: "If n is even, the length of the transformed axis is (n/2)+1. If n is odd, the length is (n+1)/2.": so the return of `rfft` cannot have the same length as `a`. Maybe try with less values than 20.

Comment: Jean-François is right: try with `a = numpy.random.rand(21)`. If you don't specify `len(a)`, it returns 20 values, not 21.

Comment: The "See Notes below" comment on the `irfft` docs is misleading though, as the explanation referred to by @Jean-FrançoisFabre is actually in the docs for `rfft` and not in the Notes section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, omitting the length works if the length is even, but not if it is odd:

```
numpy.random.seed(123456)
a = numpy.random.rand(21)
# array([0.12696983, 0.96671784, 0.26047601, 0.89723652, 0.37674972,
#        0.33622174, 0.45137647, 0.84025508, 0.12310214, 0.5430262 ,
#        0.37301223, 0.44799682, 0.12944068, 0.85987871, 0.82038836,
#        0.35205354, 0.2288873 , 0.77678375, 0.59478359, 0.13755356,
#        0.85289978])
numpy.fft.irfft(numpy.fft.rfft(a))
# array([0.24111601, 0.90078174, 0.37803686, 0.86982605, 0.38581891,
#        0.29202917, 0.72002065, 0.59446031, 0.23485829, 0.55698438,
#        0.42253411, 0.26457788, 0.49961714, 1.06138356, 0.45849842,
#        0.22863701, 0.68431715, 0.73579194, 0.14511054, 0.82140976])
```

The documentation for the return values of [`numpy.fft.rfft`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html) and [`numpy.fft.irfft`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.irfft.html) explains why this happens, although the reference to the “Notes” section for `numpy.fft.irfft` is still misleading:

> **numpy.fft.rfft**(a, n=None, axis=-1, norm=None)
>
> **Returns:**
>
> **out : complex ndarray**
>   The truncated or zero-padded input, transformed along the axis
>   indicated by *axis*, or the last one if *axis* is not specified. If
>   *n* is even, the length of the transformed axis is `(n/2)+1`. If *n* is odd, the length is `(n+1)/2`.

---

> **numpy.fft.irfft**(a, n=None, axis=-1, norm=None)
>
> **Returns:**
>
> **out : ndarray**
>   The truncated or zero-padded input, transformed along the axis indicated by *axis*, or the last one if *axis* is not specified. The length of the transformed axis is *n*, or, if *n* is not given, `2*(m-1)` where `m` is the length of the transformed axis of the input. To get an odd number of output points, *n* must be specified.